# Show that $x^2 + x + 2\in \mathbb{F}_5[x]$ is irreducible

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

Other than the brute force method of plugging in $i\in\{0, \dots, 4\}$ and showing $f(i) \not\equiv 0 \pmod 5$, what's the proper way to argue this with factorizations or gcd maybe?

Comment: I'd say plugging in is the proper way. What could be simpler?

Comment: You could also use the quadratic formula, if you know that $b^2 - 4ac$ isn't a square in $\mathbb F_5$.

Comment: How do I know that $$b^2 - 4ac$$ isn't a square in $\mathbb F_5$?

Comment: Is there a way to do this by showing that the coefficients of this polynomial are in F_p?

Comment: The proper way is to brute force, then appeal to factor theorem. If the polynomial were reducible, we would have to be able to decompose it into a product of two linear factors, and factor theorem + brute force computation imply that the polynomial has no linear factors.

Comment: The [Jacobi symbol calculator](http://math.fau.edu/richman/jacobi.htm) tells us that $\left(\frac{3}{5}\right)=-1$, so $3=-2=-7$ is not a square modulo $5$. Why $-7$? Because $b^2-4ac=-7$ with your polynomial.

Comment: Actually, I think plugging in doesn't fully suffice since $deg(x^2 + x + 2) < 5$. So we'd definitely need to consider the coefficients. If by factor theorem we have $(ax+b)(cx+d)$, then we know $ac = 1$ and $bd=2$. So all the coefficients are in $F_5$ which proves it I think?

Comment: Trying to solve with quadratic formula indeed gives a negative determinant, is that enough to say there are no factors? What is meant by "isn't a square in $\mathbb F_5$?

Comment: @webmathex $t$ not being a square in $\Bbb F_5$ means that, for all $v\in\Bbb F_5$, $v^2\ne t$. There is no such thing as "negative (or positive) numbers" in $\Bbb F_5$.

Comment: Isn't $\mathbb F_5 = \mathbb Z_5$? And what is $t$ here?

Comment: @webmathex I don't understand why $\operatorname{deg}(x^2 +x +2) < 5$ is relevant. Factor theorem works for all polynomials, of all degrees, with coefficients in any field.

Comment: Ah actually, I think you're right and I confused myself, sorry. I commented on the order < 5 because if it were = 5 and there are no roots, then the number of elements in the factored field $\mathbb Z_p[x]/f(x)$ would be maximal.

Comment: Another thing I just read is that for something to be irreducible, if $x^2 + x + 2 = h(x), g(x)$ for some $h(x), g(x)\in\mathbb F_5[x]$, then either $h(x) = \pm 1$ or $g(x) = \pm 1$. How could one argue this formally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simplify that quadratic using $1 \equiv -4\pmod5$.

$$ x^2+x+2 \equiv x^2-4x+2 \equiv (x-2)^2-2 \pmod5$$
So if your poly is reducible,

$$(x-2)^2\equiv 2 \pmod5$$
has a solution.

But the only quadratic residues mod 5 are $\{0,1,4\}$. Hence the poly is irreducible.

---

Alternatively,
$$ x^2+x+2 \equiv x^2+6x+9-7  \equiv (x+3)^2 - 2 \pmod 5$$

Comment: That's a neat trick. How do we find the quadratic residues? I'm not familiar with that concept

Comment: @webmathex [Quadratic residue theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_residue) is a huge topic that all the "big names" of early modern number theory made important contributions to, in particular Euler, Gauss, Lagrange, and Legendre. There are various equations & algorithms for determining if $x^2=n\pmod m$ has a solution, but when $m$ is small, the fastest way is to just do a brute-force search.

Comment: I spent some time searching it up just now. Seems like the brute force way is to try all values $0 \leq n \leq \lfloor \frac{m}{2}\rfloor$?

Comment: So the residues are directly linked to the number of solutions? And since $2$ does not appear for $\mathbb F_5$ then this poly is irreducible because it has no solution. Does this relate to it's factorization containing a constant element?

Comment: @webmathex For a prime modulus, we have the simple situation that zero has one square root (itself), and all the other quadratic residues have two solutions, $\pm x$. That can be extended to prime powers, using [Hensell lifting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hensel%27s_lemma). Things get a little more complicated with composite modulus, but you can use the [Chinese Remainder theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem) to combine prime power solutions.

Comment: @webmathex You may enjoy exploring the [Alpertron calculators](https://www.alpertron.com.ar/NUMBERT.HTM)

Comment: I think the thing OP is missing in this conversation is that if a polynomial of degree two has no roots in a field $F$ then it is irreducible over $F$.

Comment: @Gerry Maybe, although they do seem to understand that if "$f(i) \not\equiv 0 \pmod 5$" then it's irreducible.

Comment: Thanks for the discussion, super helpful :)

Comment: @PM2Ring So if we lift the solution using Hensel's, then are we showing that there are powers of two increases in solutions for each lift?

Comment: @webmathex There's some good info & examples on Hensel lifting here: https://brilliant.org/wiki/hensels-lemma/

Comment: @PM2Ring Yep, those examples look great, but are notationally a bit tough on the brain.

Comment: @PM2Ring am also wondering, if we consider a field mod our irreducible function here, how can we determine if $3x + 2$ is a primitive root of this modulus group $\mathbb F_5[x] / x^2 + x + 2 \mathbb F_5[x]$? I'm trying to use the fact that if this is a cyclic group, which I think has an order of $25$, then $f(x)$ is a primitive root iff $f(x)^{order / p} \neq e$ where $p$ prime. How does the divisibility of $p | order$ relate to the primitivity of roots in some group?

Comment: @webmathex I think we're getting beyond the scope of a simple comment thread. ;) It's probably a good idea to have a solid foundation in plain modular arithmetic before getting into more complicated Finite Fields. I know a bit about that topic, but I'm certainly not an expert, and I don't want to say something wrong or misleading. FWIW, SageMath has nice support for [Finite Fields](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/finite_rings/sage/rings/finite_rings/finite_field_constructor.html). I'll post a tiny demo that just lists the elements of GF(5^2) in the next comment.

Comment: [GF(5^2) demo](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJwNijsKgDAQBXtP8bBJgqkEm0DaHEMQXGEhP9ZE9PZmypkJ8AicuVFgiqfe9tVCHcoilbPHfvt3X5d3GVaoile1xE-Z6SoCtnjAGZR7Ijka6WDchEEVzk2PPrt5TOYHR_seTQ==&lang=sage)

Comment: GF(5^2) int representation [addition & multiplication tables](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJyVjL8KwjAchPc8xS3ll5jiEHARuuYFOqqFQiJE0qTkT-njG0UXN2-8--7TGKBdcMVqZ73hp0n1oJl6LNFUX_OwT0rusrXJrmkgFwoJNrZbjqlYw7Vga2otp9mYNt1jwgYXMJ4ZWj4j6PiILvALdSoTOvAqN4EXXd_0TQj2NV3DUv1frsOv6wn6Qj3p&lang=sage)

Comment: $F_5[x]/\langle x^2+x+2\rangle$ is a non-cyclic group of order $25$ **under addition**, but when primitive roots come up, that's for the nonzero elements, which form a cyclic group of order $24$ **under multiplication**. So $f$ is a primitive root if neither $f^{12}$ nor $f^8$ is $1$, the multiplicative identity.